# Same string is throwing error for toMatch() method Jasmine

Tags: javascript, arrays, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

**I am trying to write a test case for drop down**

- Test case one: if values.length > 0 then populating dropdown with
  list
- Test case two: if values.length ===0 then displaying NO RESULTS FOUND

**Test case one** is working properly.
but for **test case two** I am facing **error**

I tried with Methods **toContain() , toEqual().** but no luck.
Below is the code for it.

> ***HTML***

```
<p id="noResultFound" *ngIf="values.length === 0" class="k-popup filter-search-list">No Results Found</p>
```

> **Component.sepc.ts  file**

```
[![it('should show "No Results Found" if options are not listed', () => {

        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchSelectComponent);
        const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        comp.show = true;
        comp.values = \[\];
        comp.field = 'SearchList';
        comp.placeholder = "search for company";
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
        expect(comp.values).toEqual(\[\])
//getting error at below line
        expect(compiled.querySelector('#noResultFound').textContent).toMatch('No Result Found');
    });
```

[image]

Comment: `No Results Found` ... `No Result Found` - is that deliberate? .. Result***s*** vs Result

Comment: I found the issue I actually checking with wrong spelling , my mistake 
apologies.

Comment: but they are two different strings ... Result**S** is not the same as Result

Comment: i.e "No Results Found"  does not match 'No Result Found' - yet you expect it to do so - hint: there's an `s` at the end of one Result that isn't in the other Result, therefore the strings are not the same

Comment: `toMatch` is used to test against Regex (https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). The HTML has `No Results Found` so you should do something like: `expect(compiled.querySelector('#noResultFound').textContent).toEqual('No Results Found');`